# Symbolic Derivative of An Array

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following code with symbolic variables and two arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from sympy.physics.vector import dynamicsymbols

t = sp.symbols('t')     #time
q1,q2 = dynamicsymbols("q1,q2")    # variables

P1 = np.array([[q1],[0],[0]])
P2 = np.array([[q1-l*sp.sin(q2)],[l*sp.cos(q2)],[q2]])
```

I want to take the derivative of each element in the array with respect to time t.

```
V_P1 = sp.diff(P1,t)
V_P2 = sp.diff(P2,t)
```

I keep getting errors and don't know how to get sympy to take the derivative of the arrays. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the "*" for?

Comment: I don't see any errors!

Comment: Sorry, the * was a typo. Its not in my code. The error I get is "ValueError: 
Can't calculate derivative wrt -l*sin(q2(t)) + q1(t)." I also get "First variable cannot be a number: 0" when trying to differentiate P1.

Comment: I am using PyCharm. I copied my code into Jupiter notebook and it works just fine. Weird.

Comment: Use the Array class in SymPy